# Hanging a thinner interior door on original frame

Tags: doors, door-frame, hinges, interior, renovation

We live in a 1950's house and are replacing the internal doors. We've bought new doors of the same height and width as the originals, however they don't seem to be made as thick as they used to be. The height and width are a beautiful fit, but the depth of the old doors was ~42mm, whereas the new doors are only 35mm deep. The result is that we have deep gaps on the hinge jamb as shown in the picture below:

[image: Hinge jamb]

And the resulting gap when closed:

[image: Gap]

Is there a standard approach to the problem of fitting a thinner door in a door frame originally for a deeper door? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Typically we would just move the stop back towards the door but in your case it might be necessary to add a stop extension.

If you have access to a table saw you could make short work of this. Measure the width of the stop, the distance from the stop to the door and make the cuts. Install with some wood glue and pin nails then you can caulk it and paint.